# React. Children as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know how to pass children to React component:

```
<Button block
        href={url}
        target="_blank"
        bsStyle="primary"
        bsSize="xsmall">Open This Wonderful Link</Button>
```

But can I use this way:

```
<Button block
        href={url}
        target="_blank"
        bsStyle="primary"
        bsSize="xsmall" 
        children="Open This Wonderful Link" />
```

**It works**, but is this normal? Can I use this way every time?

P.S. Sorry for my poor English..)

Comment: You wont to pass react elem to component in some props, or you wont to use exactly "children" prop?

Comment: I want to pass children as property in JSX element. In some cases it is more convenient. @SergeyOrlov, are you Russian?

Comment: You can pass children as props. But you also can pass component as other props `someName= {components}` and then use them `this.props.someName`.

Comment: Yes this is not only normal but expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `children` is like any other `prop` and can be used as a `prop` to render child components, instead of nesting child components in the respective element

Comment: Nice) Thanks a lot.

Comment: What will happened if you also pass children as nested components?

Comment: When you do pass children as nested component along with `children` prop, `React` gives higher precedence to the nested component. That is, the node sent in `children` prop is ignored

Comment: And what type of values can we pass ? Passing functionnal components does not seem to work well (e.g. `children: (props) => <h1>hello</h1>`)

Comment: `React` `children` should be a `React` Component and not a `function`. In your case you will have to invoke that function, something like `children = {((props) => (<h1>hello</h1>))()}`